# Numpy - sorting numbers, representing a network of nodes, in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, numpy

Say I have an array representing a network of nodes with connected nodes described as 'from nodes' and 'to nodes':

```
a = array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 9),
       (9, 10), (10, 11), (2, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)], 
      dtype=[('fnode', '<i4'), ('tnode', '<i4')])

a['fnode']
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  2,  6,  7,  2,  9, 10,  2, 12, 13, 13, 14])
a['tnode']
array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
```

How do I best combine the 'to nodes' into lists where they share the same 'from node'?

I am after this format:

```
#from-node  to-nodes
1             [2]
2             [3,6,9,12]
3             [4]
4             [5]
5             []
6             [7]
7             [8]
8             []
9             [10]
10            [11]
11            []
12            [13]
13            [14,15]
14            [16]
15            []
16            []
```

**EDIT**

To be clear, I would like 'from-nodes' with no 'to-nodes' (e.g. node 8) to be associated with an empty list.

Answer (score 5):

Use `collections.defaultdict` :

```
d = defaultdict(list)
map( lambda (k,v) : d[k].append(v), a)
print d
>> Out[40]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2], 2: [3, 6, 9, 12], 3: [4]
: [7], 7: [8], 9: [10], 10: [11], 12: [13], 13: [14, 15], 14: [16]})
```

Comment: Possible typo: `d = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Is there a way to convert a `defaultdict` to a numpy array?

Comment: you can't since the length of each elem is not constant (numpy.arry does not support variable-length nested list). If you still want to stick with numpy, you need to create an adjacency matrix

Answer (score 3):

If you already use NumPy and not lists, I suppose your goal is to speed things up. In that case I would suggest using the Pandas library.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(a).groupby('fnode').apply(lambda x: x['tnode'].values)
fnode
1                  [2]
2        [3, 6, 9, 12]
3                  [4]
4                  [5]
6                  [7]
7                  [8]
9                 [10]
10                [11]
12                [13]
13            [14, 15]
14                [16]
dtype: object
```

Timing information on a large array:

```
In [32]: a = array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8),
                    (2, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (2, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14),
                    (13, 15), (14, 16)] * 100000, 
                    dtype=[('fnode', '<i4'), ('tnode', '<i4')])
In [33]: %%timeit
         pd.DataFrame(a).groupby('fnode').apply(lambda x: x['tnode'].values)
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop

In [34]: %%timeit
         d = defaultdict(list)
         map( lambda (k,v) : d[k].append(v), a)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.76 s per loop
In [35]: %%timeit
         [(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(a, lambda (x, y): x)]
1 loops, best of 3: 9.02 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`.

Define the array:

```
A = np.array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 9),
   (9, 10), (10, 11), (2, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)], 
  dtype=[('fnode', '<i4'), ('tnode', '<i4')])
```

sort it:

```
A = sorted(A, key=lambda (a,b): a)
```

and then group it (I turn the generator into a list here so you can see its result):

```
In [18]: [(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(A, lambda (a,b): a)]
Out[18]: 
[(1, [(1, 2)]),
 (2, [(2, 3), (2, 6), (2, 9), (2, 12)]),
 (3, [(3, 4)]),
 (4, [(4, 5)]),
 (6, [(6, 7)]),
 (7, [(7, 8)]),
 (9, [(9, 10)]),
 (10, [(10, 11)]),
 (12, [(12, 13)]),
 (13, [(13, 14), (13, 15)]),
 (14, [(14, 16)])]
```

You can then do any post-processing you need.

For example, you're after something more like `[(k, map(lambda (a,b): b, v)) for k,v ...` in this example.

(Note that sorting the array *is* important.  `groupby` operates in the same way as POSIX `uniq`, in that it will only combine adjacent elements.  To combine all elements, sort by the same key as you group by.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long-winded but it works (getting the empty lists as well):

```
np.array((np.unique(np.hstack((a['tnode'],a['fnode']))),np.array([a['tnode'][x].tolist() for x in [np.where(a['fnode']==y) for y in np.unique(np.hstack((a['tnode'],a['fnode'])))]]))).T

array([[1, [2]],
       [2, [3, 6, 9, 12]],
       [3, [4]],
       [4, [5]],
       [5, []],
       [6, [7]],
       [7, [8]],
       [8, []],
       [9, [10]],
       [10, [11]],
       [11, []],
       [12, [13]],
       [13, [14, 15]],
       [14, [16]],
       [15, []],
       [16, []]], dtype=object)
```

In a (possibly) more readable form:

```
uniq_nodes = np.unique(np.hstack((a['tnode'],a['fnode'])))   # list nodes in network
to_nodes_loc = [np.where(a['fnode']==y) for y in uniq_nodes] # find where nodes are in tonodes array
to_nodes = [a['tnode'][x].tolist() for x in to_nodes_loc]     # get to_nodes
np.array((uniq_nodes,np.array(to_nodes))).T                  # combine into array
```